# tables without filter column are not getting synced in Microsoft sync frameword

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

Question about Microsoft sync framework

I have some tables in my sync scope, some of which have filter " UserId" and 4 tables have no filters.

Out of the "no filters" tables, one is working fine and is getting synced, but the 3 of the newly added tables are not getting synced

the following is my config file

ContactStatus, ContactAction, ContactActionRule tables without filters are not getting synched, though i am not getting any error.

But at the same time, Settings table which is also without filters is getting synced.
I know this will be hard to debug, but if any of you guys have any idea, please tell me.

This is how i hit the service

https:AnzuReaderSyncSyncService.svc/ARSync/DownloadChanges?fk_user_id=1902

```
 <SyncConfiguration>
        <SyncScopes>
          <SyncScope Name="ARSync" SchemaName="dbo" IsTemplateScope="true" EnableBulkApplyProcedures="true">
            <SyncTables>
              <SyncTable Name="[ContactStatus]" GlobalName="ContactStatus" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="StatusName" GlobalName="StatusName" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="LastUpdatedBy" GlobalName="LastUpdatedBy" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DeleteMark" GlobalName="DeleteMark" SqlType="bit" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
              </SyncTable>
              <SyncTable Name="[ContactAction]" GlobalName="ContactAction" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Action" GlobalName="Action" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="LastUpdatedBy" GlobalName="LastUpdatedBy" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
              </SyncTable>
              <SyncTable Name="[ContactActionRule]" GlobalName="ContactActionRule" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_ContactAction_Id" GlobalName="FK_ContactAction_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_OriginalState_Id" GlobalName="FK_OriginalState_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_SenderState_Id" GlobalName="FK_SenderState_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_ContactState_Id" GlobalName="FK_ContactState_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="LastUpdatedBy" GlobalName="LastUpdatedBy" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
              </SyncTable>
              <SyncTable Name="[UserLibrary]" GlobalName="UserLibrary" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="[side].FK_User_Id = @FK_User_Id">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="uniqueidentifier" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Name" GlobalName="Name" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Description" GlobalName="Description" SqlType="nvarchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_User_Id" GlobalName="FK_User_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="ParentId" GlobalName="ParentId" SqlType="uniqueidentifier" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="SequenceNo" GlobalName="SequenceNo" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="IsRecycled" GlobalName="IsRecycled" SqlType="bit" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="LastUpdatedBy" GlobalName="LastUpdatedBy" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
                <FilterColumns>
                  <FilterColumn Name="FK_User_Id" />
                </FilterColumns>
                <FilterParameters>
                  <FilterParameter Name="@FK_User_Id" SqlType="int" DataSize="0" />
                </FilterParameters>
              </SyncTable>

              <SyncTable Name="[Discussion]" GlobalName="Discussion" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="[side].FK_User_Id = @FK_User_Id">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="ParentId" GlobalName="ParentId" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_User_Id" GlobalName="FK_User_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_Application_Id" GlobalName="FK_Application_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Title" GlobalName="Title" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Description" GlobalName="Description" SqlType="nvarchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Tag" GlobalName="Tag" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_DomainLibrary_Id" GlobalName="FK_DomainLibrary_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_Publication_Id" GlobalName="FK_Publication_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_ContentType_Id" GlobalName="FK_ContentType_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_Category_Id" GlobalName="FK_Category_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_SubCategory_Id" GlobalName="FK_SubCategory_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="PageNumber" GlobalName="PageNumber" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Text" GlobalName="Text" SqlType="nvarchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="TimeFrame" GlobalName="TimeFrame" SqlType="float" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="PositionMatrix" GlobalName="PositionMatrix" SqlType="text" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="ChapterNumber" GlobalName="ChapterNumber" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DeleteMark" GlobalName="DeleteMark" SqlType="bit" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="LastUpdatedBy" GlobalName="LastUpdatedBy" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="PubDBContentId" GlobalName="PubDBContentId" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Url" GlobalName="Url" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="ChildCount" GlobalName="ChildCount" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="RootId" GlobalName="RootId" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_Content_Id" GlobalName="FK_Content_Id" SqlType="uniqueidentifier" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
                <FilterColumns>
                  <FilterColumn Name="FK_User_Id" />
                </FilterColumns>
                <FilterParameters>
                  <FilterParameter Name="@FK_User_Id" SqlType="int" DataSize="0" />
                </FilterParameters>
              </SyncTable>

              <SyncTable Name="[Settings]" GlobalName="Settings" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Key" GlobalName="Key" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Title" GlobalName="Title" SqlType="nchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DefaultValue" GlobalName="DefaultValue" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Description" GlobalName="Description" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Type" GlobalName="Type" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
              </SyncTable>

              <SyncTable Name="[UserContact]" GlobalName="UserContact" SchemaName="" IncludeAllColumns="true" FilterClause="[side].SenderId = @FK_User_Id">
                <SyncColumns>
                  <SyncColumn Name="Id" GlobalName="Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="SenderId" GlobalName="SenderId" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="ContactId" GlobalName="ContactId" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="false" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="FK_ContactStatus_Id" GlobalName="FK_ContactStatus_Id" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="ContactName" GlobalName="ContactName" SqlType="varchar" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="Follows" GlobalName="Follows" SqlType="bit" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateAdded" GlobalName="DateAdded" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="DateUpdated" GlobalName="DateUpdated" SqlType="datetime" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                  <SyncColumn Name="LastUpdatedBy" GlobalName="LastUpdatedBy" SqlType="int" IsPrimaryKey="false" IsNullable="true" />
                </SyncColumns>
                <FilterColumns>
                  <FilterColumn Name="SenderId" />
                </FilterColumns>
                <FilterParameters>
                  <FilterParameter Name="@FK_User_Id" SqlType="int" DataSize="0" />
                </FilterParameters>
              </SyncTable> 
          </SyncScope>
        </SyncScopes>
        <Databases>
          <TargetDatabase Name="ARSyncDB" DbServer="50.56.173.145" DbName="ARDevDB2.0Sync" UserName="sabeta" Password="sa123$" UseIntegratedAuth="false" />
        </Databases>
      </SyncConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

enable sync fx tracing or sql profiler to see what's going on under the hood. you may also check for conflicts or constraints (especially FKs) that may prevent changes from being applied.